# Sprite background span for list navigation

Tags: html, css

I'm running into problems using a sprite image for navigation icons. Not only only is my background position offset not working, but it shoulds the background image across the whole length of the navigation, it's almost like i need to define the width and height of the image shown.

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/737YT/1/

```
.navigation {
}
.navigation li {
}
.navigation li a {
    background: url(http://www.otlayi.com/web_images/content/free-doc-type-sprite-icons.jpg) no-repeat left center;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.navigation li a:hover {
    background-color: #495C6D;
}
.navigation li a.active {
    background-color: #495C6D
}
#rss span {
    background-position: -15px 0;
}
#photos span {
    background-position: -30px 0;
}
#links span {
    background-position: -45px 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Might have been more helpful if you showed me how instead

Comment: Just set the height and width of the elements.

Comment: What elements though. Setting .navigation span {width: 50px} does nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

1. Drop the background image from `.navigation li a`
2. This CSS

---

```
#links span,
#photos span,
#rss span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    background: url(http://www.otlayi.com/web_images/content/free-doc-type-sprite-icons.jpg) no-repeat left center;
}
#rss span {
    background-position: -50px -65px;
}
#photos span {
    background-position: -330px -125px;
}
#links span {
    background-position: -130px -5px ;
}
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/737YT/2/)

Answer (score 1):

More than just setting the width and height of anything. In the end, since you are using the `span` elements for displaying the images you need to do a few things.

First, you need to add styles for `span`. This includes moving the background to the span, changing it to an inline-block level element, giving it dimension and preventing overflow.

Next, position the background appropriately per span as you had attempted previously.

Modified styles shown here:

```
.navigation li span {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(http://www.otlayi.com/web_images/content/free-doc-type-sprite-icons.jpg) no-repeat left center;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#rss span {
    background-position: -52px -68px;
}
#photos span {
    background-position: -90px -66px;
}
```